# Как настроить драйвер iron в Laravel 5.0?

Tags: laravel, очередь

Помогите настроить очереди с драйвером iron. Когда выполняю команду

```
artisan queue:subscribe SendEmail http://mysite.com/queue/receive
```

Выходит ошибка **Class 'IronMQ' not found in и т.д.** Уже пробовал менять версию *iron-io/iron_mq* в composer.json при этом удалял папку venodor и чистил cache композера. Но все-равно **Class 'IronMQ' not found** Может, настраивал уже кто на Laravel 5.0?